# React-Native FlatList with 3 cards paging layout

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview, react-native-stylesheet

In [this snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@amirvxj/carousel-flatlist-paging) I am trying to have 3 cards in the center of the screen with a horizontal FlatList and enabled paging to jump to the next 3 cards on scroll.

But the layout starts getting destroyed after scrolling and some pixels of the next/previous card appears in the view.

How should I style this list to always have exactly 3 cards in the center of the screen and scroll will jump to the next page with the next 3 cards ? Or like the GooglePlay store, a fixed pixels of previous/next card be visible to the left and right of the main 3 cards. (Example screenshots below)

```
 <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent: 'center', marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5,}}>
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => `ìtem-${item}`}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Card style={{width:Dimensions.get("window").width/3-5,marginRight:5}}>
            {/* some content */}
          </Card>
        )}
      />
 </View>
```

I do not need a library like `snap-carousel` or so ...

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### use Scrollview prop [snapToOffsets](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#snaptooffsets) to achieve that.

like google play example ( one by one ) try [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmed_gaber/flatlist-snap-carousel2?platform=android).
[image]

your example ( three by three ) try [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmed_gaber/flatlist-snap-carousel?platform=android).
[image]

##### how to use snapToOffsets?

```js
const snapToOffsetsLikeGooglePlay = data.map((x, i) => {
    return ((i * itemWidth) + startScroll)
})

const snapToOffsetsLikeYourExample = data.map((x, i) => {
    return ((i * (itemWidth) * previewCount) + startScroll)
})

//see the example below to know 
//what is `startScroll` and `previewCount` mean? 
//and how to calculate `itemWidth`?
```

here the full example

```js
import React from 'react';
import {FlatList, Text} from 'react-native';
import { View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
//you need to preview n items.
const previewCount = 3;
//to center items
//the screen will show `previewCount` + 1/4 firstItemWidth + 1/4 lastItemWidth 
//so for example if previewCount = 3
//itemWidth will be =>>> itemWidth = screenWidth / (3 + 1/4 + 1/4)
const itemWidth = width/(previewCount + .5);
//to center items you start from 3/4 firstItemWidth 
const startScroll = (itemWidth * 3/4);


const App = () => {

    const data = [...Array(24).keys()];
    const flatlistRef = React.useRef();

    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (flatlistRef.current) flatlistRef.current.scrollToOffset({
            offset:startScroll, animated: false
        });
    }, [flatlistRef]);


    const snapToOffsetsLikeGooglePlay = data.map((x, i) => {
        return ((i * itemWidth) + startScroll)
    })

    const snapToOffsets = data.map((x, i) => {
        return ((i * (itemWidth) * previewCount) + startScroll)
    })


    return (
        <FlatList
            ref={flatlistRef}
            style={styles.container}
            pagingEnabled={true}
            horizontal= {true}
            decelerationRate={0}
            snapToOffsets={snapToOffsets}
            snapToAlignment={"center"}
            data={data}
            renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                <View style={styles.view} >
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{index}</Text>
                </View>
            )}/>
    );

}



export default App;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {

    },
    view: {
        marginTop: 100,
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
        width: itemWidth - 20, //20 is margin left and right
        margin: 10,
        height: 140,
        borderRadius: 10,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
    },
    text : {
        fontSize : 60,
        fontWeight : 'bold',
        color : '#aaa',
    },

});
```

#### update: start from zero as @Amir-Mousavi comment

one by one try [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmed_gaber/flatlist-snap-carousel4?platform=android)
1-) comment useEffect.
2-) set `const startScroll = (itemWidth * 3/4)`

[image]

three by three try [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmed_gaber/flatlist-snap-carousel3?platform=android)
1-) comment useEffect.
2-) set `const startScroll = (itemWidth * 2.75)`

[image]

Comment: Very nice, but the list always starts at index 1, and 0 is already passed a card

Answer (score 3):

Ok after much work and testing I finally was able to fix this.

`snapToInterval` have to snap to interval a full length of the screen.

if you use `pWidth *3` it wont work. Now you may ask why, I really do not understand , it may have something to do with float values.

But if you use `snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('window').width}` it should work.

Have a look at [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@alentoma/carousel-flatlist-paging) example

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but running the snack, the list always jumps to the beggining.

Comment: Ok friend Was able to pay much more time and testing and was able to fix it. Have a look at my edited answer again.